# What is the purpose of QEventLoop::wakeUp()?

Tags: qt, qeventloop

I am using a custom event processing with `QEventLoop::processEvents()` to make some piece of code synchronous... I have seen `QEventLoop::wakeUp()` in the documentation which says:

> Wakes up the event loop.

Looks like too little for me. What does `QEventLoop::wakeUp()` actually do and when should I call it?

Comment: It causes event loop to return from a function that could block .. ! Yeah that's also too little ; [QAbstractEventDispatcher::aboutToBlock()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracteventdispatcher.html#aboutToBlock)